# Calling table frame layout element from Python Toolbox using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, python-toolbox, table-frame

I created a Python Toolbox which calculates statisitics about some layers and print a pdf layout.

The layout and table frame elements already exist.

[image]

I try to access the table frame elements from my Python script to do some modifcations on fields to show, field order and table frame position.

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  # my project
m = aprx.listMaps("Map2")[0]  # my map
lyr = m.listLayers("Clip_Reco_Dissolve1")[0]  # source layer for the table frame
lyt = aprx.listLayouts('Tabloid_Paysage_Unique_test')[0]  # my layout
fieldNames = ["Categorie", "COUNT_Categorie"]  # fields to display

elm = lyt.listElements("GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "Categorie ressource")  # name of the table frame in the layout content
```

The only way I found in [Esri documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/graphicelement-class.htm) is using last row, but it is not working. I tried again after converting this element to graphic, but it doesn't work either, and anyway I need to manipulate it as table frame to manage fields, before changing its position.

```py
elm = lyt.listElements("GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "Categorie ressource")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1840, in listElements
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.listElements(*gp_fixargs((element_type, wildcard), True)))
RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are going to have to use the [CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) to reach into the table frame structure.
Look at the TableFrame examples in the [ArcGIS Pro Python CIM Samples](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8772f61319584882bb697ba003030636).